# How extensive should negative unit test cases be?

Tags: java, junit

I am pretty new to unit testing, and am aware that, for any non-primitive type parameter, a test should be written in which said parameter is provided as null. Should I also be including a negative test in which the parameter has a field which has a field whose being null could impact the method being tested, and so on?

For example, in the code provided the parameter of type Cart has a field which is a list of `CartLine`s. This `CartLine` class has a field of type Product, which, if provided as null in the one of the `CartLines` constituting the list of `CartLine`s that constitutes the field of the `Cart` being provided as a parameter, would produce a `NullPointerException` in the method being tested. Should I be providing a unit test for this possibility?

```
 public void updateProductQuantities(Cart cart){
    for (CartLine cartLine : cart.getCartLineList()) {
        Optional<Product> productOptional = productRepository.findById(cartLine.getProduct().getId());
        if (productOptional.isPresent()){
            Product product = productOptional.get();
            product.setQuantity(product.getQuantity() - cartLine.getQuantity());
            if (product.getQuantity()<1){
                productRepository.delete(product);
            }else {
                productRepository.save(product);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Should I be providing a unit test for this possibility?" no. You don't have infinite time. Focus on testing the things that are truly important. Otherwise the important stuff becomes lost in a sea of trivialities.

Comment: You should test that your code never puts you in that situation. Testing that an NPE is thrown when an object is null is not that useful.

Comment: Is a `CartLine` without a `Product` valid? It's better to design so that you don't get into situations where your objects may be in strange states. Then you wouldn't need to even think about this kind of test.